# Node.js PUT API request fails first time on server restart. Works the rest of the times

Tags: node.js, api, asynchronous, put

My PUT request always fails the first time after a server restart, but works after the first attempt has failed. My GET/DELETE/POST requests works fine all the time.

I tried having the itemid as a const instead of having it as a global variable to make sure it was not a async problem regarding that variable

```
public async PutSomething(metadataObject: any, id: any) {
    const params = {"id": id};
    const itemidquery = "SELECT itemid FROM archive WHERE id = " + "${id};";
    let itemid: any;
    try {
        itemid = await connection.db.one(itemidquery, params);
    }
    catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    }
    console.log("The itemid for the item to be updated" + itemid.itemid);
    const urlFinal = BASEURL + "items/" + itemid.itemid + "/metadata";
    console.log(urlFinal);
    const headersOpt = {
        "rest-dspace-token": process.env.TOKEN,
        "content-type": "application/json"
    };
    const options = {
        rejectUnauthorized: false,
        method: "PUT",
        uri: urlFinal,
        headers: headersOpt,
        body: metadataObject,
        json: true,
        encoding: "utf8",
    };
    rp(options)
    .then(async function (res: Response, req: Request) {
        console.log("Successful PUT" + res as any);
    })
    .catch(function (err: Error) {
        console.log("Error while updating julkaisu: " + id + " with error: " + err);
    });
    }
```

This should work fine in my opinion, since all my other API routes works fine, GET/DELETE/POST etc. This just fails the first time after a server restart, no matter what. After that it keeps working fine.
Anyone have any idea what might cause this?

Comment: Whats the error message you are getting when it fails?

Comment: Just a StatusCode error: 500 - undefined

Comment: do you have a connection open with your database on the application start? `connection.db` Perhaps the first start it attempts to connect? Also really curious if this is just a sample of your function but you don't update anything in your method? you only fetch the object and log...